# Python: print random text (taken from database) and combine 2 words, if I click a button? I already have code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Since I already have a code that I am attaching, how can I manipulate the text and do these two things?

1. If I click on Button 1: in the vertical column "Word 1" of the database, is a random/casual word taken from among the various ones and then printed in the multiline textbox?
2. If I click on Button 2: in the vertical column "Word 2" a random/casual word is taken from among the various ones, and also in the vertical column "Word 3" a random/casual word is taken from among the various ones. Then both words are combined/merged and printed in the multiline textbox in this example way (with space): "gggggg ooooooo" or "Hello world".

I'm just starting out with Python. Can you show me the code of the 2
questions I asked, please? Thank you and excuse me

[image]
[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

window=Tk()
window.title("gfff")
window.geometry("700x700")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

### BUTTON ###
button = Button(window, text="Button", bg='white')
button.pack()
button.place(x=5, y=330)

button2 = Button(window, text="Button 2", bg='white')
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=5, y=380)

### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

##### FOR BUTTON #####
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/xxxxxxx/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT Word 1 FROM TableExample')

##### FOR BUTTON 2 #####
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/xxxxxxx/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT Word2, Word3 FROM TableExample')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: did you commit the execution `con.commit()`  and you are fetching all data so you have to use `cursor.fetchall()` to see the result.

Comment: Ah ok, cursor.fetchall(). Thank you. I'm just starting out with Python. Can you show me the code of the 2 questions I asked, please? Thank you

Comment: for random selection you can use `random` python module or you can change you sql query to like `'SELECT Word 1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`  , `SELECT Word2, Word3 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`  this will give one row randomly then use `cursor.fetchone()` use in tkinter according to you

Comment: Thank you. instead the action inside the button how can I put it? let me explain: I'm not very familiar with tkinter. i saw that you use command inside. what should i write in command?

Also how do I put the code to print inside the textboxt ... by clicking on the button? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also beginner in `tkinter` so i am just showing simple example to do it. `command` in button take function name so you can assign function to button. i am creating two different function so whenever that button click that associate function execute . i am using `cursor` and first text box `text` as global that's why they are accessible in function and  you can use `inesrt` for inserting text . read documentation for better understanding

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/xxxxxxx/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

window=Tk()
window.title("gfff")
window.geometry("700x700")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

def fetch_word_one():  # setting this to button 1
    cursor.execute('SELECT Word 1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
    word1 = cursor.fetchone()
    text.insert(tk.END,word1)

### BUTTON ###
button = Button(window, text="Button", bg='white',command=fetch_word_one)
button.pack()
button.place(x=5, y=330)



def fetch_words_two_three(): # setting this to button 2
    cursor.execute('SELECT Word2, Word3 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
    word2,word3 = cursor.fetchone()
    text.insert(tk.END,f"{word2} {word3}")
 
button2 = Button(window, text="Button 2", bg='white',command=fetch_words_two_three)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=5, y=380)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. For educational purposes, your help is very valuable to me. You said that you are a beginner too, maybe if someone reads ... they can perfect your code (in case you need it, but I don't think so, that's fine for me too. Good). Thank you :) I have a few small questions please:

1) What does F mean in the text.insert line (tk.END, f "{word2} {word3}")? What is F used for?

2) Are the words Word2 and Word3 separated by the right space? " "?

Comment: 3) I noticed that in Command you have linked the function. Interesting. Out of curiosity: if I want to insert a much longer and more substantial code in the button, can I connect two or more functions to the button? Or even a class?

Comment: `f""` using to format string , you can also use `format` see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @GiovanniRusso   yes you can insert more complex stuff in button and you pass one function to `command` so you have  combine all these two functions in one then pass it to button

Comment: Ah ok. I forgot to ask an important thing in the question. What if I wanted to combine two words from two different tables? For example Word5 of the TableExample1 and Word6 of the Table Example2? How should I write the sql ('SELECT Word2, Word3 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM () LIMIT 1') to get words from two different tables?

Comment: @GiovanniRusso   try the code as you want , why so much thinking for that it's just gonna give error so try it whatever comes in your mind to solve this. you can write two single queries like `select word1 from table1` and `select word2 from table2` then add in  python or can write single query `select  table1.word1 , table2.word2 from table1, table2 order by random() limit 1` which will return two words add in python or  can use query like `select table1.word1 || table2.word2 from table1, table2 order by random() limit 1`  return one word from these tables. try & see what fits you

Comment: Ah OK. A little curiosity: what is LIMIT1? Why is it used?

Comment: `limit 1` for the only one result because `select * from table` gives all rows in table .

Comment: Ah, ok, perfect. I got it. Thank you. I voted for you. I just posted another Python question called "Get a row from database corresponding to ID and replace data in the textbox when prompted". If you have time / want, can you check it out? Thank you