# Get a row from database corresponding to ID and replace data in the textbox when prompted

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

For educational purpose I am using Python, Tkinter and Sqlite to create small prefabricated sentences, with small language templates like **text.insert (tk.END, f "{City_Name} {is a city that owns} {Inhabitants} {inhabitants} {on a surface of} {Surface} ").** The result should be (by way of example I remain the parentheses): {Paris} {is a city that owns} {2 229 095} {inhabitants} {on an area of} {105 km²}

The app starts with the selection of the Country in a combobox and then with the selection of the City in the combobox in the next combobox, for example "Paris", which in the database corresponds to City_Name. So the whole app focuses on city selection in the second combobox. So how can I retrieve from the row all the other data (Inhabitants, Name inhabitants, Surface, Language of the database) corresponding to "Paris", in order to automatically display them in the textobox, replacing them when requested?
[image]

To replace them when prompted automatically when prompted, I mean the curly brackets in text.insert, i.e. {Inhabitants}, {Surface}, etc.

*IMPORTANT: In this way, I don't have to write the code for every single city, but I can write only one code that is valid for all the cities, because they automatically change {City_Name}, {Inhabitants}, {Surface}*

P.S: I don't want to focus on a specific city, but obviously when you change the name of the city in the Combobox City, the data also changes (the row of data in the database), taking those corresponding to the selected city.

Can you please help me and show me the part of the code I need? Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

window=Tk()
window.title("aaa")
window.geometry("700x700")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

### BUILD PHRASE ###
def build_phrase():
    cursor.execute('SELECT City_Name, Nation, Inhabitants, Name_inhabitants, Surface, 
    Language FROM TableExample') 
    text.delete(1.0,END)

    text.insert(tk.END, f "{City_Name} {is a city that owns} {Inhabitants}
    {inhabitants} {on an area of } {Surface}") 

### BUTTON ###
button = Button(window, text="Button", bg='white', command = build_phrase)
button.pack()
button.place(x=5, y=330)

### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

### CONNECT DATABASE ###
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/test/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

### NATION COMBOBOX ###
def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Nation FROM TableExample')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

### CITY COMBOBOX ###
def combo_city(event=None):
    val = nation.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT City_Name FROM TableExample WHERE Nation = ?', (val,))
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    city['value'] = result
    city.current(0)
    return result

nation=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
nation['value'] = combo_nation()
nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)
nation.place(x=5, y=150,height = 25, width = 180)


city=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
city.place(x=5, y=180, height = 25, width = 180)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood by reading the question and comments, this should be what you are looking for:

```py
def build_phrase():
    city_name   = city.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE City_Name=?',(city_name,))
    results     = cursor.fetchone()
    
    cursor.execute('SELECT Word 1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM () LIMIT 1') # Similarly do all 10 queries like this
    word1       = cursor.fetchone()

    inhabitants = results[3]
    surface     = results[5]

    text.delete(1.0,END)
    text.insert(tk.END, f"{city_name} {word1} {inhabitants} {{inhabitants on an area of}} {surface}")
```

You were looking for individually querying the database for each items, which is really unnecessary when you can get the same result by indexing the fetched total results too.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. A small addition please: let's take the example that "is a city that owns" is a sentence contained in a database (different table), and together with this sentence there are others (for example 10 others) in a vertical column of a field called "phrase1". How can I make sure that instead of "is a city that owns" a sentence is taken randomly and always displayed in text.insert.......? With Sql ('SELECT Word 1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM () LIMIT 1').  Which code should I add and where? Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I have edited with an example

Comment: Very very well, thank you. You are very kind. WHERE City_Name =? ', (City_name,)) takes the whole line for example, from Paris, takes France, 2229095, Parisians, 105 and French? Wouldn't it take an IF city.get (and something else, I don't know) (of the combobox), considering that the city is chosen in the combobox?

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I do not understand you

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not speak english very well. Wondering if the SQL WHERE City_Name =? ', (City_name,)) .... takes all horizontal fields of a city in the database. For example, if I selected "Paris" in the combobox, then France, 2229095, Parisians, 105 and French are automatically taken. I also asked if it was not the case to also insert an IF of the City combobox for SQL in the function. Excuse the questions, but I don't speak English well, I want to make sure you understood correctly

Comment: @GiovanniRusso Why is there Paris in cities combobox? It is not a city

Comment: If it's not a city, then what is Paris? :)

Comment: However, the app is mainly based on the first combobox that chooses the country, and then the second combobox that chooses the city. In the code you wrote me, did you make sure that all the data of the database row of the city selected in the City combobox is taken? I'm talking about cursor.execute ('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE City_Name =?', (City_name,)). Did you understand correctly what I ask in the question? Forgive me, but I'm just asking why I don't speak English well and I don't know if I expressed myself well

Comment: @GiovanniRusso Oh sorry I saw the france in the question and got carried away. Yea all the data is taken based on the city

Comment: @GiovanniRusso ~ Would appreciate marking this as the correct answer if this answered your questions correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Comment: Yes. I definitely would :) I wanted to test the code first. Where I live is the time zone and when you wrote me the code I went to sleep. Today I had to work and now I'm ahead of the pc. Your answer is the one that helped me and I will mark it. But there is a very small problem. The result that appears in the textobox is thus Paris ("wordddd",) 2 229 095 {inhabitants on an area of} 105 km².

Comment: How can I delete the two round brackets and the double quote from word, and also the curly bracket in {inhabitants on an area of}? I tried to delete a brace (since you have rightly written two), but it gives me the error. How can I correct to remove these things? Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I have explained that issue explained over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462874/i-am-getting-on-the-end-of-my-output-what-is-causing-this-and-how-do-i-remo/67462950#67462950), you can do similarly :D

Comment: Thank you. I read that you have to convert the string. In the link example you wrote ans1 = (* map (str, spell), "") and blank4.insert (0, '' .join (ans1)). In my case what would it be like? If you answer me, then we close the question and vote for you as the best answer. I'm starting out with Python. I'm sorry

Comment: @GiovanniRusso For example if your variable is called `var` then, `''.join(var)` will do.

Comment: Do I have to write it inside text.insert or outside? In my case text insert is text.insert (tk.END, f "{city_name} {word1} {inhabitants} {{inhabitants on an area of}} {surface}"). The variable to convert is {word1} and {{inhabitants on an area of}}. How should I write?

Comment: @GiovanniRusso Inside....`text.insert(tk.END, f "{city_name} {''.join(word1)} {inhabitants} {{inhabitants on an area of}} {surface}")`

Comment: Ah ok, perfect. Thank you. And what about {{inhabitants on an area of}}? Wonder why there are two curly brackets. I tried to do this, but it gives me an error
{'' .join {inhabitants on an area of}}. Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso It has curly braces because in the question you mentioned you need curly braces inside it, if not, then just remove curly braces around it: `text.insert(tk.END, f "{city_name} {''.join(word1)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")`

Comment: I wrote {'' .join (inhabitants on an area of)} but it gives me an error

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I already told you what to write: `text.insert(tk.END, f "{city_name} {''.join(word1)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")` OR if you want to do what you do(which is totally unnecessary): `{'' .join('inhabitants on an area of')}`

Comment: OK understood. Thank you very much and sorry for a few too many questions. You have been very kind. I appreciate. Voted you :)

Comment: Do you talk about the votes in the comments? If so, voted

Comment: I voted first, long time ago. I voted your answer as the best (green tick). I also voted some of your comments as helpful (orange up arrow). I did not understand what you are asking me. However, I only registered on StackOverflow a few days ago. I'm trying to understand. If I am doing something wrong, I apologize, but it is therefore lack of knowledge. I have the utmost respect for you who answered me

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I appreciate you taking the time to reply, upvoting comments is not what I mean, above the green tick mark there are two triangles, one pointing down and other pointing up, the one pointing up is called up vote and I recommend you press it for people who have helped you with answering your questions :D To understand better, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVHXe.png) image.

Comment: Aaaaaaah, ok. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is replace the function with this

```py
def build_phrase():
   cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM testExample where City_Name=?',city.get())
   row=cursor.fetchall()
   text.delete(1.0,END)
   list1=[rowq for rows in row for rowq in rows]
   print(list1)
   #list1=str(list1).replace("'","").replace("[","").replace("]","")
   name_city=list1[1]
   surface=list1[-2]
   people=list[3]
   text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {{is a city which owns}} {people} {{inhabitants on a surface of}} {surface}")
```

Comment: Your way is great and I thank you very much, but it's not quite what I was looking for. Isn't it possible to use another way instead of using list1 [1], list1 [3] and list1 [-2]? A way to write directly (explicitly, visibly, literally) the database field name and not list1 [1], etc? For example Inhabitants, Surface = cursor.fetchone () and then call them text.insert (tk.END, f "{City_Name} {is a city which owns} {Inhabitants} {inhabitants on a surface of} {Surface}") . Can you show me another way please more like what I'm looking for? Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso, I am fetching all the values. However way you fetch it, it will always return a nested tuple like ```(('1','2'),('3','4'))```. Also, ```.format``` is used for variable. From ```is a city which owns```, it looks like a string. It should not be inside the ```{}```.

Comment: QUESTION 1: I understand. Look at this question for a moment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67945725/python-print-random-text-taken-from-database-and-combine-2-words-if-i-click. A nice guy replied to me using word1 = cursor.fetchone () and then text.insert (tk.END, f "{word2} {word3}"), which are the two words of the database field. So the column field written directly. I know the example is different, but couldn't something similar be done?

Comment: Actually, I am not so well versed with ```SQL```

Comment: QUESTION 2: As in the link of question 1, "is a city which owns" is a sentence contained in the database, because I would like to print sentences (similar, but which fit well in grammar and logic) in a random way. Another database table contains sentence columns, of which I will take a random one. To pick it up randomly and insert it in the sentence (together with list1) what can I do? What should I add to the code? In the link example there is cursor.execute ('SELECT Word 1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM () LIMIT 1'). How should I enter it in the case of the code you wrote me? Thank you

Comment: I'll explain. I don't speak English very well, sorry. If you wanted to use your code kindly write me, but add for example "is a city which owns" which is randomly taken from another table called TablePhrase, in the field called "phrase2", how can you add this in your code? That is to add this to the already present List1 of Inhabitants, etc? To get Random I use this ('SELECT phrase2 FROM TablePhrase ORDER BY RANDOM () LIMIT 1'). Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso, I am a little busy, Can I contact you later

Comment: Letter? What do you mean? I'm new to Stack Overflow. If there is a way to contact me, ok, contact me. Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso, Just slip of my tongue. :)

Comment: I'm not understanding, sorry. Ahahahah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233734/discussion-between-sujay-and-giovanni-russo).

Comment: There is no point in what you are asking @GiovanniRusso. What you can do is individually store those on a variable instead, like `foo = lst[0]` and then insert this. There is literally no extra benefit of doing individual queries.

Comment: OP is using SQLite and `%s` is not the placeholder there, its `?`.

Comment: @Cool Cloud Can you write an answer by showing me the code you talk about with foo = lst [0]? I'm just starting out with Python. Thank you. P.S: I tried to test cursor.execute ('SELECT * FROM testExample where City_Name =% s', city.get ()) but it doesn't work. Could there be some distraction / sql error? Doesn't it take an IF City.get?

Comment: Parameters should be like a tuple.